# Looking for story about genius traveling for training at space station

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Story is about a man who possesses a very high IQ and is accepted to a space station (planet?) where others like him also live.  He is able to travel back in time and watch the battle of Hastings.  He questions why he is there

Comment: How old is the story?

Comment: Written in the 60's.  Maybe Simak, Sturgeon, Silverberg

Comment: He time-travels from his space station to the Battle of Hastings? Does he time-travel under his own power, or does he have a time machine?

Comment: He uses a machine to view what happened in any past event

Answer (score 6):

Randomly spotted this old question in the sidebar and noticed it didn't have an accepted answer.

I'm pretty sure this is Clifford Simak's "Immigrant", previously the answer to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73738/sci-fi-short-story-about-the-smartest-people-taken-to-another-planet).

The destination was a planet, not a space station, of advanced telepathic aliens, who are carefully selecting the brightest people from Earth.

The main character, Bishop, tries out a gadget called a "live-it" which can immerse the user in a scene from anywhere in history:

> What type of history, sir?” the  face in the screen asked him.
>
> “Type?”
>
> “Galactic, Kimonian, Earth — almost any place you wish.”
>
> “Earth, please,” said Bishop.
>
> “Specifications?”
>
> “England,” said Bishop. “October 14, 1066. A place called Senlac.”
>
> And he was there.
>
> He was no longer in the room with its single chair and its four bare walls, but he stood upon a hill in sunny autumn weather with the gold and red of trees and the blueness of the haze and the shouts of men.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds quite a bit like [*Macroscope*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macroscope_(novel)) by Piers Anthony.

As Sean Duggan points out there may not be anything about the Battle of Hastings in Macroscope (been a while since I read it) but the remaining elements are a close match so it's at least worth checking out. It's a fun book by Piers Anthony in his prime

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the SF&F Stack. Could you please expand your answer a bit by explaining _why_ you think this might be the answer?

Comment: It looks like a decent match to me. There's a space station, a genius, a device to look back in time. The only missing factor is that I see no mention of the Battle of Hastings in plot summaries.

Comment: If you can actually add mention of the matching details in your answer, you run a good chance of getting that downvote reversed. :)