# Story that might have house, simple mind, in title

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for a short story written pre-1975. It has a future world where children are educated to enter a specific guild. The hero is at the top of his class, but does not get selected for his guild. Shunned by family, he is sent away, where he discovers the real reason for his failure: he is too important as a thinker.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/48031/which-sf-book-had-intelligence-testing - Possible dupe

Comment: Please let us know if the posted answer is the story you were looking for. (If it is, instead of posting a comment, you can simply [accept](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) the answer of your choice by clicking on the check mark next to it.

Comment: Instead of commenting thanks under the answer you can accept it by clicking the little green tick below the upvote button.

Answer (score 6):

This is almost certainly Asimov's ["Profession"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profession_(novella)):

> George Platen is determined to be a Computer Programmer, a profession
>   in demand, and he hopes to qualify for "export" to a top-flight
>   Outworld. On Reading Day, however, concerns are raised about George's
>   ability to be Educated. On George's Education Day, he is told that his
>   brain is unfit for any form of Education. He is drugged and sent to a
>   House for the Feeble Minded.

"House" and "Simple mind" are not in the title, but they are referred to almost verbatim - "House for the Feeble Minded".

And there, indeed, George discovers that he's wanted as a thinker:

> George is returned to the House and discovers the reality: the House
>   is an Institute of Higher Studies. Those people who have the urge and
>   persistence to create, even though they have been told otherwise about
>   their abilities, are sent there to support the advancement of science
>   and civilization.

Comment: And if so, a duplicate of this one; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6642/story-where-the-protagonist-is-turned-off-from-an-automated-system-of-profession